# How can I drag and drop sort nodes and output result as JSON?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have tried the [DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module, but it creates a new table in the database that is not related with the entity fields of my entity and I'm using AngularJS as front-end with JSON API calls, so I just want to know if there is a way to do this Drag and Drop which also alter the table of the Entity in the database?

Comment: Have you already checked if you can configure the DraggableViews view to output you some JSON you can use? Maybe with an additional display?

Comment: The question title maybe better should be: "How can I drag and drop sort nodes and output result as JSON?" which probably is too broad, but then maybe "How can I output DraggableViews order as JSON?" is specific enough. But you should definitely try that yourself first.

Comment: The table in the DB is not related to the entity, really? I mean all you need are node IDs, no? Are there really no entity IDs in this table?